# How to update state value of variable that uses custom Hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, react-hooks

My Component has form input fields. These made use of a useState hook with their value and setValue for each input field. I want to optimize my component so the input fields made use of the same custom Hook which I called useFormInput

Inspired by Dan Abramov https://youtu.be/dpw9EHDh2bM see at 49:42

This works perfectly. However now I want to update the username after a new exercise is created. This is in the onSubmit method. But I'm not sure how to do this. Before I refactored I could use setUserName(), but now username is set by the generic custom hook function useFormInput

the username has an onChange method, so I thought I can maybe use this. However this uses the e.target.value because it is used for an input field.

Component:
I commented out the setUserName(''), here I want to update the username

```
  const CreateExercise = () => {
  const inputEl = useRef(null)
  const username = useFormInput('')
  const description = useFormInput('')
  const duration = useFormInput(0)
  const date = useFormInput(new Date())
  const [users, setUsers] = useState([])
  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get('http://localhost:5000/users/')
      .then(res => {
        if (res.data.length > 0) {
          setUsers(res.data.map(user => user.username))
        }
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err))
  }, [])
  const onSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault()
    const exercise = {
      username: username.value,
      description: description.value,
      duration: duration.value,
      date: date.value
    }
    axios
      .post('http://localhost:5000/exercises/add', exercise)
      .then(res => console.log(res.data))
      debugger
    // setUsername('')
    window.location = '/'
  }
```

custom Hook useFormInput:

```
const useFormInput = initialValue => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(initialValue)
  const handleChange = e => {
    const newValue = e.target ? e.target.value : e
    setValue(newValue)
  }
  return {
    value,
    onChange: handleChange
  }
}
```

I expect the value in the state of username is updated to an empty string ' '

Complete code is on my repo on https://github.com/jeltehomminga/mern-tracker

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of trying to maintain more than 1 state, I'd recommend combining all state into one object. Then you can move everything into your custom hook. In addition, always make sure you handle and communicate any errors to the user.

**Working example**:

[image: Edit Hooks - Create Exercise Form]

---

### State as an object

**hooks/useFormHandler** (the `API` defined below is an object with functions to mimic API calls -- you'll replace this with real API calls. Also, if you wanted to make this hook reusable for other `form` components, then you'll need to remove the `useEffect` and `handleSubmit` functions from the custom hook and place them inside the specified functional component instead)

```
import { useCallback, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import API from "../../API";

// create a custom useFormHandler hook that returns initial values,
// a handleChange function to update the field values and a handleSubmit
// function to handle form submissions.
const useFormHandler = initialState => {
  const [values, setValues] = useState(initialState);

  // on initial load this will attempt to fetch users and set them to state
  // otherwise, if it fails, it'll set an error to state.
  useEffect(() => {
    API.get("http://localhost:5000/users/")
      .then(res => {
        if (res.data.length > 0) {
          setValues(prevState => ({
            ...prevState,
            users: res.data.map(({ username }) => username)
          }));
        } else {
          setValues(prevState => ({
            ...prevState,
            error: "Unable to locate users."
          }));
        }
      })
      .catch(err =>
        setValues(prevState => ({ ...prevState, error: err.toString() }))
      );
  }, []);

  // the handleChange function will first deconstruct e.target.name and
  // e.target.value, then in the setValues callback function, it'll
  // spread out any previous state before updating the changed field via
  // [name] (e.target.name) and updating it with "value" (e.target.value)
  const handleChange = useCallback(
    ({ target: { name, value } }) =>
      setValues(prevState => ({ ...prevState, error: "", [name]: value })),
    []
  );

  // the handleSubmit function will send a request to the API, if it
  // succeeds, it'll print a message and reset the form values, otherwise,
  // if it fails, it'll set an error to state.
  const handleSubmit = useCallback(
    e => {
      e.preventDefault();

      const exercise = {
        username: values.username,
        description: values.description,
        duration: values.duration,
        date: values.date
      };

      // if any fields are empty, display an error
      const emptyFields = Object.keys(exercise).some(field => !values[field]);

      if (emptyFields) {
        setValues(prevState => ({
          ...prevState,
          error: "Please fill out all fields!"
        }));
        return;
      }

      API.post("http://localhost:5000/exercises/add", exercise)
        .then(res => {
          alert(JSON.stringify(res.message, null, 4));
          setValues(prevState => ({ ...prevState, ...initialState }));
        })
        .catch(err =>
          setValues(prevState => ({ ...prevState, error: err.toString() }))
        );
    },
    [initialState, setValues, values]
  );

  return {
    handleChange,
    handleSubmit,
    values
  };
};

export default useFormHandler;
```

**components/CreateExerciseForm**

```
import isEmpty from "lodash/isEmpty";
import React, { Fragment } from "react";
import { FaCalendarPlus } from "react-icons/fa";
import Spinner from "react-spinkit";
import Button from "../Button";
import Input from "../Input";
import Select from "../Select";
import useFormHandler from "../../hooks/useFormHandler";

const fields = [
  { type: "text", name: "description", placeholder: "Exercise Description" },
  { type: "number", name: "duration", placeholder: "Duration (in minutes)" },
  {
    type: "date",
    name: "date",
    placeholder: "Date"
  }
];

// utilize the custom useFormHandler hook within a functional component and
// pass it an object with some initial state.
const CreateExerciseForm = () => {
  const { values, handleChange, handleSubmit } = useFormHandler({
    username: "",
    description: "",
    duration: "",
    date: "",
    error: ""
  });

  // the below will show a spinner if "values.users" hasn't been fulfilled yet
  // else, it'll show the form fields. in addition, if there's ever a 
  // "values.error", it'll be displayed to the user.
  return (
    <form
      style={{ width: 500, margin: "0 auto", textAlign: "center" }}
      onSubmit={handleSubmit}
    >
      {isEmpty(values.users) ? (
        <Spinner name="line-scale" />
      ) : (
        <Fragment>
          <Select
            name="username"
            placeholder="Select a user..."
            handleChange={handleChange}
            value={values.username}
            selectOptions={values.users}
            style={{ width: "100%" }}
          />
          {fields.map(({ name, type, placeholder }) => (
            <Input
              key={name}
              type={type}
              name={name}
              placeholder={placeholder}
              onChange={handleChange}
              value={values[name]}
            />
          ))}
          <Button type="submit">
            <FaCalendarPlus style={{ position: "relative", top: 2 }} /> 
            Create Exercise
          </Button>
        </Fragment>
      )}
      {values.error && <p>{values.error}</p>}
    </form>
  );
};

export default CreateExerciseForm;
```

---

### State as independent data types

Or, if you insist on using separated states, then create a `resetValue` function in the `useFormInput` hook:

```
const useFormInput = initialValue => {
  // initialize state from "initialValue"
  const [value, setValue] = useState(initialValue)

  // handle changes to the "value" state via updating it
  // with e.target.value
  const handleChange = useCallback(({ target: { value } => {
    setValue(value)
  }, []);

  // reset the value back to initialValue
  const resetValue = useCallback(() => {
    setValue(initialValue);
  }, []);


  return {
    value,
    handleChange,
    resetValue
  }
}
```

Then, destructure properties for the username (and other states, if needed):

```
const CreateExercise = () => {
  // use ES6 destructure and aliasing to extract and rename the 
  // "value" (as username), "handleChange" function (as 
  // handleUsernameChange) and "resetValue" function (as resetUsername)
  const { 
    value: username, 
    handleChange: handleUsernameChange, 
    resetValue: resetUsername 
  } = useFormInput('')

  ...other form state

  ...useEffect(() => {}, [])

  const handleSubmit = useCallback(e => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const exercise = {
      username: username,
      description: description,
      duration: duration,
      date: date
    };

    axios
      .post('http://localhost:5000/exercises/add', exercise)
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res.data)
        // only reset the username if the exercise was successfully
        // created
        resetUsername();
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err.toString());

  }, [date, description, duration, resetUsername, username]);

  return ( ...form )
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the different approach. The code sandbox with comments is very usefull and you're right I need to hanlde the errors.

I did make deliberate choice to put the state fields in separate variables as this was recommended in by Dan Abramov if you check th YouTube video around 26 minutes. I can see however that I would not run in to my problem if I would put everything in an object since you can easily reset the form to initial values. Still would like to know how to update the state if I wouldn't put all the fields in an object.

Comment: To me, it doesn't make much sense to have 5 separate sets of state and 5 separate sets of functions to update them, especially since they are a part of a `form`. That said, you could just return a callback function to reset the specific state back to its `initialValue` within your `useFormInput` hook. When you use the `useFormInput` hook, destruct its properties (like the `useFormHandler` example above), and utilize the reset function within a `handleSubmit` function. I've updated the answer to include this approach.

Comment: Cool! That was what I was looking for! Ah, yes if I destruct I can then use the handleSubmit for the username. You make a valid for you approach. What I was thinking is that it seems unnecessary to update an object with all the form fields with every onChange on a field, since they are updated/changed separately. On the other hand that's what we always do when we use setState. Thanks for taking the effort to explain how this would work with the other approach :)

Answer (score 0):

I took a look and did a PR - Formik implementation w/validation.

Here is the PR - https://github.com/jeltehomminga/mern-tracker/pull/1

#### UI View

```js
<>
  <h3>Create New Exercise Log</h3>

  <pre>{JSON.stringify({ formData }, null, 2)}</pre>

  <ExerciseForm {...{ users }} onChange={data => setFormData(data)} />
</>
```

#### CreateExercise Form

```js
import React from "react";

import * as Yup from "yup";
import { Formik, Form, Field } from "formik";

import DatePicker from "react-datepicker";
import cx from "classnames";

const requiredMessage = "Required";

const exerciseFormSchema = Yup.object().shape({
  username: Yup.string().required(requiredMessage),
  description: Yup.string()
    .min(2, "Too Short!")
    .required(requiredMessage),
  duration: Yup.number()
    .integer()
    .min(1, "Min minutes!")
    .max(60, "Max minutes!")
    .required(requiredMessage),
  date: Yup.string().required(requiredMessage)
});

const ExerciseForm = ({ users = [], onChange }) => {
  return (
    <Formik
      initialValues={{
        username: "",
        description: "",
        duration: "",
        date: ""
      }}
      validationSchema={exerciseFormSchema}
      onSubmit={values => onChange(values)}
    >
      {({
        values,
        touched,
        errors,
        handleChange,
        handleBlur,
        isSubmitting,
        setFieldValue
      }) => {
        const getProps = name => ({
          name,
          value: values[name],
          onChange: handleChange,
          onBlur: handleBlur,
          className: cx("form-control", {
            "is-invalid": errors[name]
          })
        });

        return isSubmitting ? (
          // Replace this with whatever you want...
          <p>Thanks for the Exercise!</p>
        ) : (
          <Form>
            <FormControl label="Username">
              <>
                <select {...getProps("username")}>
                  <>
                    <option value="default">Select user...</option>
                    {users.map(person => (
                      <option key={person} value={person.toLowerCase()}>
                        {person}
                      </option>
                    ))}
                  </>
                </select>
                <FormErrorMessage {...{ errors }} name="username" />
              </>
            </FormControl>

            <FormControl label="Description">
              <>
                <Field {...getProps("description")} />
                <FormErrorMessage {...{ errors }} name="description" />
              </>
            </FormControl>

            <FormControl label="Duration in minutes">
              <>
                <Field {...getProps("duration")} type="number" />
                <FormErrorMessage {...{ errors }} name="duration" />
              </>
            </FormControl>

            <FormControl label="Date">
              <>
                {/* Was present before refactor */}
                <div>
                  <DatePicker
                    {...getProps("date")}
                    selected={values.date}
                    minDate={new Date()}
                    onChange={date => setFieldValue("date", date)}
                  />
                  <FormErrorMessage {...{ errors }} name="date" />
                </div>
              </>
            </FormControl>

            <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">
              Create Exercise log
            </button>
          </Form>
        );
      }}
    </Formik>
  );
};

export default ExerciseForm;

// Created to manage label and parent className
const FormControl = ({ label, children }) => (
  <div className="form-group">
    <label>{label}:</label>

    {children}
  </div>
);

const FormErrorMessage = ({ name, errors }) => {
  const error = errors && errors[name];

  return error ? (
    <div
      class="invalid-feedback"
      // Add inline style override as error message cannot sit as sibling to datePicker (bootstrap css)
      style={{ display: "block" }}
    >
      {error}
    </div>
  ) : null;
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your contribution. Matt answered my question more specific. For me the pull request contains too much other changes that are not related to my question.

Comment: No problem, nothing wrong with a quick prototype . I would note there is little validation / no custom date picker you chose on the chosen answer. However some great detail and extensive notes with rationale! You were fortunate with this question 